# How to set keyboard focus to a child when its parent is made visible?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a `ListBox` with editable items. When you edit an item the first time, the edit control (a `TextBox` in this minimal example) initially has keyboard focus. The second time an item is edited, the `TextBox` does not have keyboard focus. If you test the code, items are put into edit mode by selecting them and pressing F2 or Return.

Is there any reasonable and direct way to make the `TextBox` always get keyboard focus when it becomes visible? Failing that, is there an unreasonable or indirect way that works reliably?

It's not feasible to use the edit template at all times, because the real edit template includes many things, such as a 300 px high `ListBox` with a thousand options, and a `TextBox` for filtering the contents of the `ListBox`. I tried doing this with the `CellTemplate` of a *DevExpress GridControl*, but that was a can of worms for a variety of reasons.

The reason I'm alternately showing/hiding two content controls is that when I just swap different templates into `ListBox.ItemTemplate`, focus is handed off to the window.

**XAML:**

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:ViewModel />
</Window.DataContext>
<Grid>
    <ListBox
        ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
        >
        <ListBox.Resources>
            <DataTemplate x:Key="DisplayTemplate">
                <Label Content="{Binding Value}" />
            </DataTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:Key="EditTemplate">
                <WrapPanel FocusManager.FocusedElement="{Binding ElementName=TextBox}" Focusable="False">
                    <Label>Editing:</Label>
                    <TextBox Margin="4,2,2,2" Text="{Binding Value}" x:Name="TextBox" />
                </WrapPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.Resources>
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <ContentControl x:Name="Display" Content="{Binding}" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource DisplayTemplate}" />
                    <ContentControl x:Name="Edit" Content="{Binding}" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource EditTemplate}" Visibility="Collapsed" />
                </Grid>
                <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsEditing}" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="Edit" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                        <Setter TargetName="Display" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </DataTemplate.Triggers>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ListBoxItem}}">
                <EventSetter Event="KeyDown" Handler="ListBoxItem_KeyDown" />
            </Style>
        </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

**ViewModels.cs**

```
public class ViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public ViewModel()
    {
        Items = new ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel>(
            new[] { "ytesadamy", "ugexudunamo", "wovaxatytol", "imuq" }.Select(s => new ItemViewModel() { Value = s }));
    }

    public ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel> Items { get; private set; }
}

public class ItemViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    #region Value Property
    private String _value = default(String);
    public String Value
    {
        get { return _value; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _value)
            {
                _value = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
    #endregion Value Property

    #region IsEditing Property
    private bool _isEditing = default(bool);
    public bool IsEditing
    {
        get { return _isEditing; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _isEditing)
            {
                _isEditing = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
    #endregion IsEditing Property
}

#region ViewModelBase Class
public class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    #region INotifyPropertyChanged
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallerMemberName] string propName = null) =>
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
    #endregion INotifyPropertyChanged
}
#endregion ViewModelBase Class
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually do this with a behavior:

```
public static class FocusOnVisibleBehavior
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty FocusProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
        "Focus",
        typeof(bool),
        typeof(FocusOnVisibleBehavior),
        new PropertyMetadata(false, OnFocusChange));

    public static void SetFocus(DependencyObject source, bool value)
    {
        source.SetValue(FocusProperty, value);
    }

    public static bool GetFocus(DependencyObject source)
    {
        return (bool)source.GetValue(FocusProperty);
    }

    private static void OnFocusChange(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var element = d as FrameworkElement;
        DependencyPropertyChangedEventHandler handler = (sender, args) =>
        {
            if ((bool)args.NewValue)
            {
                // see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13955340/keyboard-focus-does-not-work-on-text-box-in-wpf
                element.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Input, new Action(delegate()
                {
                    element.Focus();         // Set Logical Focus
                    Keyboard.Focus(element); // Set Keyboard Focus
                    //element.SelectAll();
                }));

            }
        };

        if (e.NewValue != null)
        {
            if ((bool)e.NewValue)
            {
                element.IsVisibleChanged += handler;
                element.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Input, new Action(delegate ()
                {
                    element.Focus();         // Set Logical Focus
                    Keyboard.Focus(element); // Set Keyboard Focus
                                             //element.SelectAll();
                }));
            }
            else
            {
                element.IsVisibleChanged -= handler;
            }
        }

        //  e.OldValue is never null because it's initialized to false via the PropertyMetadata()
        //  Hence, the effect here is that regardless of the value that's set, we first add the 
        //  handler and then immediately remove it. 
        //if (e.NewValue != null)
        //{
        //    element.IsVisibleChanged += handler;
        //    element.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Input, new Action(delegate ()
        //    {
        //        element.Focus();         // Set Logical Focus
        //        Keyboard.Focus(element); // Set Keyboard Focus
        //                                 //element.SelectAll();
        //    }));
        //}
        //if (e.OldValue != null)
        //    element.IsVisibleChanged -= handler;
    }
```

Can't remember if I wrote this code myself or got it from somewhere else, either way you use it like this:

```
<TextBox behaviors:FocusOnVisibleBehavior.Focus="True" ... etc ... />
```

Comment: Thanks Mark! I’ll give it a whirl in the morning. At a glance it looks like it ought to do the trick.

Comment: Hi Mark, it works. Thanks! I fixed a bug and took the liberty of updating the answer to reflect the fix. Hope you don't mind.