# How to set cursor focus to a TextBox?

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox

How to set cursor focus to a TextBox?

I have a window pop up with a `TextBox` and would like to focus the cursor to it. So a user can directly type text.

I could not find a proper property. Is there one?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1345391/set-focus-on-textbox-in-wpf

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To set focus on a `textbox` when your form loads you can do this:

```
private void Form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SomeTextBox.Select();
    }
```

**Note**** You have to put it within the `Form_Load` event.

Answer (score 2):

In WPF, try this:

```
FocusManager.SetFocusedElement(parentElement, txtMyTextBox)
```

Read more about `FocusManager.SetFocusedElement` [**here**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.focusmanager.setfocusedelement%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

**OR**

```
txtMyTextBox.Focusable = true;
Keyboard.Focus(txtMyTextBox);
```