# Where does keyboard focus go when the focused WPF element is removed?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a custom TreeView-like control in a panel in my application. As you click on items they receive keyboard focus.

It's possible to select a set of items in the tree and cut or remove them by pressing Ctrl-X or Delete. When the tree items are removed, keyboard focus reverts to the main window.

This leads to trouble - if I Undo my cut, I get my elements back but keyboard focus is no longer on my panel so I can't (for example) go cut-undo-cut-undo-cut.

What determines where the keyboard focus moves when an element is removed? I quickly tried making my panel have IsFocusScope="True" but that didn't seem to have any effect, and the [Focus Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969768(v=vs.100).aspx) doesn't mention how to control where focus goes when an element is removed.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your best bet might be setting the focus manually after undo/redo (maybe encapsulating this in a behavior which listens to the events `FocusManager` sends?)

See also [Set focus on textbox in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1345391/232175)