# how to set focus on a textbox or passwordbox

Tags: wpf, xaml, textbox, focus, passwordbox

how to set focus on this when i log in to my application ,when log in window will open i want to type the password on this without using mouse

```
<PasswordBox x:Name="passwordbox"  Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"  Margin="5,35,5,5" Width="280"  Height="27" app:PasswordBoxAssistant.BindPassword="true" app:PasswordBoxAssistant.BoundPassword="{Binding TechUserModel.UserId,Mode=TwoWay,ValidatesOnDataErrors=True,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center">
```

Comment: `passwordbox.Focus()` on window loaded

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set focus on textbox in WPF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1345391/set-focus-on-textbox-in-wpf)

Comment: i want to directly type when application become start using this code i get focus on that textbox but i can not type my password without setting cursor using mouse on that so i want directly type my password ....

Comment: Just tested from scratch with many controls and a PasswordBox. it is working with FocusManager.FocusedElement="{Binding <ElementName>}" on the parent container. The PasswordBox is focused and you can type. Check your styles (?!)

Answer (score 2):

I have tried various solutions for this scenario and the most effective that I have found is using FocusManager.FocusedElement:

```
<Window x:Class="StackOverflow.Test"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Test" Height="300" Width="300"
        FocusManager.FocusedElement="{Binding ElementName=Box}">
    <Grid>
        <TextBox x:Name="Box"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: We could also use passwordbox.Focus() in windows loaded event.

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION:**

```
passwordbox.Focus();
```

or in .xaml file include the following in the  element as its attributes.

```
FocusManager.FocusedElement="{Binding ElementName=passwordbox}">
```

**NOTE:**

If you want to decide which control to give focus to when the form first appears, put the code in the Loaded event.

```
Loaded += (o, e) => {
  passwordbox.Focus();
};
```