# WPF textBox Focus()

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox

I have a textBox which is being used for the Search engine inside my Form as parameter. The KeyDown event on the textBox calls a method on Enter. After that I need the focus to be placed on the same textbox. How can I place the focus on that textBox ?

the code:

```
private void txtName_KeyDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
            {
                btnSearch_Click(sender, e);
                txtName.Focusable = true;
                txtName.Focus();
            }
        }
```

It seems that is not working. So how can I make this work ?

Comment: You should use the [FocusManager.SetFocusedElement(...)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.focusmanager.setfocusedelement%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: These answers might help [Set focus on textbox in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1345391/set-focus-on-textbox-in-wpf)

Comment: Thank you, I don't know why focus() doesn't work. It seems that the focusmanager takes into consideration that I'm using a menu which has the textbox(txtName) inside of it...

Comment: I've solved it using the following: 

private void txtName_LostKeyboardFocus(object sender, KeyboardFocusChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            IInputElement elem = e.NewFocus;
            DependencyObject d = elem as DependencyObject;
            
            if (FocusManager.GetIsFocusScope(d))
            {
                d.SetValue(FocusManager.FocusedElementProperty, sender as DependencyObject);
            }
        }