# Set textbox as focused element

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am trying to set focus on a text box. I tried [set focus for cursor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1345391/set-focus-on-textbox-in-wpf)

but all that does is put the cursor there and freezes it. You can't actually type anything still. You end up still having to click the text box to type. I did exactly as they did in that question. I read some stuff about logical focus and physical focus? Not quite sure how to go about doing what I need. Do I need to create an attached property and handle it that way? I am trying to avoid code behind at all costs.

Also, after clicking a "Submit" button I would like to have it set focus back to the text box again

Here is the code I tried, the FocusManager is on a grid that wraps the textbox:

```
FocusManager.FocusedElement="{Binding ElementName=FocusedTextBox}"


<TextBox Text="{Binding serialNumber}"
         x:Name="FocusedTextBox">
</TextBox>
```

As I said, all this did is put the cursor there and you can't type anything until you again click in the text box. Any suggestions?

Thanks,

Comment: why are you trying to avoid the code behind at all costs? sounds to me like you'll want to make use of event handlers, which will reside in your code behind...

Comment: Because using code behind is just bad practice in general. I'd rather use attached properties and maintain MVVM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just give the textbox a name (e.g. "theTextBox') and call `theTextBox.Focus()`.

If you're trying to do this in MVVM with data-binding (and you should be) then you can use [an attached property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1356045/set-focus-on-textbox-in-wpf-from-view-model-c) to bind to a property in your view model.

Comment: Yes I'm trying to maintain MVVM. Could you give an example of the attached property I need to use.

Comment: Look at the accepted answer on my link, there's full source code.